# Как выполнить JavaScript средствами Delphi?

Tags: jquery, delphi, javascript

Добрый вечер!

Задача такая: На сайте есть зашифрованный JavaScript код, который генерирует контрольную сумму (набор цифр) для следующего запроса. Эта сумма нужна для дальнейшей работы с сайтом.

Цель: нужно выполнить зашифрованный JS код и получить это значение. Чтобы продолжить работу с сайтом.

Comment: Перенести код генерации хеша на язык делфи, что тут сложного? Давай JS код, будет тебе дешифрованный.

Comment: http://www.sendspace.com/file/og7jdd

Comment: @Factory ну вы предоставьте код, чтобы было понятно, как оно работает. Я же не знаю, что как работает и куда передается хеш. Возможно хеш вообще создается на сайте :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разве что использовать движок IE. Если JS использует этот движек(например доступ к DOM страницы), что наверняка так и есть, то без браузера вам никак.

В сети полно интерпретаторов JS для delphi. Сомневаюсь, что они воспримут обустфицированный JS код, как это делает браузер.

Попробуйте интерпретировать JS на Delphi как код, и самостоятельно считать эту сумму.